# Determine if Observable is "completable"

Tags: rxjs

I often facing a situation, where I can't determine easily if the observable is "completable" or not. What I mean under completable? Let say we have:

**service.ts**

```
...

public getData(): Observable<number[]> {
    // Obviously in real application there would be something more meaningful
    return of([1, 2, 3]);
}

...
```

**component.ts**

```
...

public updateData(): void {
    this.serviceA.getData.subscribe(
        newData => this.data = newData
    );
}

...
```

In our `service.ts` we have method `getData()`, which returns data, through `Observable` and after that it completes.

Why I want to know if it completes? Because if it completes, it means I don't need to unsubscribe from that after my component gets destroyed. Obviously in trivial cases it doesn't matter that much, but if you are working in teams on a large codebase, you every time need to figure it out.

Comment: Do you have an example of an observable that doesn't complete? I'm afraid this is impossible due to the *Halting problem* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem

Comment: For e.g. if I'm listening for key or mouse events.

Comment: Yeah, I think that's impossible due to the halting problem. Sorry

Comment: There is no mechanism through which an observable can advertise to potential subscribers whether or not it completes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, there is no way to infer solely by the type of `Observable` whether it will complete at any future point in time or not. The [Observable Contract](http://reactivex.io/documentation/contract.html) does not include such semantics. However, I could imagine the following solutions:

#### 1: Let someone else handle unsubscribing

I found it a good practice to not get involved with subscribing or unsubscribung when I'm not the final consumer of the Observable. By final consumer I mean the component that is ultimately using the notifications to e.g. display data.

Instead of subscribing and unsubscribing myself, I use the Angular `async` pipe as often as possible. In most instances, transformation of data can be handled with Observable `pipes`, in a way that all my intermediate components just add pipes and just the view component finally subscribes to the result Observable. If your view framework does not support this yet, I would try to find a plugin or even implement it myself.

For example, instead of assigning the result of the observable to a class property, like in your example, I'd just use the Angular template to subscribe to the Observable. The component is modified:

```
public data$: Observable<number[]>;

public updateData(): void {
    // here, modification would take place with pipes
    this.data$ = this.serviceA.getData();
}
```

And finally in the template, I'd use `async`:

```
<div *ngIf="(data$ | async) as data">
    {{ data }}
<div>
```

#### 2: Introduce a new type

Although the original observable contract does not include semantics for dealing with your issue, we could introduce an own type that wraps around an `Observable` to indicate that this observable will complete eventually. To guarantee this behaviour, we could add a timeout that completes the observable if it hasn't notified for a given time. It could look like this:

```
class ShortLivedObservable<T> extends Observable<T> {
    private constructor() {
        super();
    }
}

function asShortLivedObservable<T>(source: Observable<T>, timeout: number = 1000): ShortLivedObservable<T> {
   return source.pipe(
       switchMap(value =>
           merge(
               of(value).pipe(
                   map(value => ({value: value}))
               ),
               timer(timeout).pipe(
                   map(() => ({complete: true}))
               )
           )
       ),
       takeUntil(({value, complete}) => complete),
       map(({value}) => value)
   )
}
```

However, this solution would come with the drawback, that new semantics are introduced that don't follow the ReactiveX practices. The type would have to be passed on to the final consumer and further piping could make the observable leaky again (see issues described here: [RxJS: Avoiding takeUntil Leaks](https://blog.angularindepth.com/rxjs-avoiding-takeuntil-leaks-fb5182d047ef)).

Comment: Impressive `ShortLivedObservable` concept, but sticking it permanently with `switchMap` may limit use cases. Still, worth consideration.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the good practice is to consider all observables as ever-lasting and never "complitable". There is no direct way of determining a priori is particular observable "complitable" because this is entirely up to observable logic, which from user perspective is private and belongs to observable. Instead of doing assumptions it's better to store each subscription in controller variable and when controller get's destroyed just unsubscribe to all of them, which is safe even for already closed subscriptions.
If you have specific actions to do on observable completeness, try to implement it in `onComplete` handler.

This approach forces you to consider all below edge scenarios:

- no value will be emitted and observable will complete (empty)
- no value will be emitted and observable will not complete (empty ever-lasting)
- infinite amount of values will be emitted and observable will not complete (ever-lasting)
- one or more value will be emitted and observable will be completed